# How to add where clause on Implicit model binding?

Tags: php, laravel, model

Currently, I have projects using Laravel 5.4 and I am trying to use model binding but I need another where clause, how can I do that?

I am using the implicit model binding on my controller, how can I provide another where clause on that? the where clause is belongs to User input (from The Request instance) which means it can be null

```
public function show(Request $request, User $user){

    $selfish = $request->input('selfish','no');
    $user->where('selfish',$selfish);

}
```

the response is empty or even error, I just wanna know how can I provide another where clause belongs to Request instance.

Comment: Can you `dd($request->all());` and check what you get, and then if you get values you want, then you can add new conditions

Comment: @RahulMeshram I get the request body and params too, but when I add "where clause" on my model binding, the result is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a where() query you then need to use ->get() afterward to gather the information

```
public function show(Request $request, User $user){
    $selfish = $request->input('selfish','no');
    $user->where('selfish', $selfish)->get();

    return('example.view') //return of somekind you can also do a redirect()->back() if necessary;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* this works? Code-only answers are not very helpful, as they don't describe what was changed, or why it was changed.

Comment: Omg sorry, I forgot to add first();

Comment: @CodeBoyCode is it work with data scope? I'm when I see that with toSql() the scope query didn't show, why?